# Hanuman Chalisa is written in which dialect?

Tags: language, hanuman-chalisa

I am fascinated by the language used in Hanuman Chalisa and I have couple of questions related to Hanuman Chalisa. I hope someone will surely help me know them.

1. Who wrote Hanuman Chalisa and what does the word Chalisa means?
2. For what Hanuman Chalisa is used for and why people use it when they feel feared?
3. In which dialect of Hindi/Sanskrit it is written?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. A Chalisa is collection of 40 Chaupai which is sung by bhakt to praise the  the deed of deity with devotion. There are hundreds of Chalisa dedicated to Hindu deities ,some of them are [Ganesh Chalisa](http://www.indif.com/nri/chalisas/ganeshchalisa/ganchalisa.asp),  [Durga Chalisa](http://www.indif.com/nri/chalisas/durgachalisa/durgachalisa.asp), [Hanuman Chalisa](https://archive.org/details/shri-hanuman-chalisa-gita-pres-gorakhpur/mode/2up) etc. The [last Chaupai](https://archive.org/search.php?query=hanuman%20chalisa) of Hanuman Chalisa is:

> **तुलसीदास** सदा हरि चेरा।
> कीजै नाथ हृदय महं डेरा।।

Which mention the name of its author **Goswami Tuslidas**.

2. The 22-nd 23-rd, 24-th , 25-th and 26-th Chaupai of [Hanuman Chalisa](https://archive.org/details/shri-hanuman-chalisa-gita-pres-gorakhpur/page/n7/mode/2up) is

> सब सुख लहै तुम्हारी सरना।
> तुम रच्छक काहू को डर ना ॥२२॥
> आपन तेज सम्हारो आपै।
> तीनों लोक हांक तें कांपै ॥२३॥
> भूत पिसाच निकट नहिं आवै।
> महाबीर जब नाम सुनावै ॥२४॥
> नासै रोग हरे सब पीरा।
> जपत निरन्तर हनुमत बीरा ॥२५॥
> संकट तें हनुमान छुड़ावै।
> मन क्रम बचन ध्यान जो लावै ॥२६॥

Which means, In his shelter devotees gets all the comfort, there is no need to fear, he is the savior, in next Chaupai Tulsidas ji says that ghosts, *Pishacha* dont come near you when they hear the name of Hanuman ji. Those who chant his name , Hanuman ji will take away all his pain and agony. 26-th Chaupai means those who devote themselves to Hanuman ji, Hanuman ji helps them in time of need.

3. It is Written in Awadhi language in Devanagari script. Awadhi is one of the common language in modern day Uttar Pradesh of India.